# React-share LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, share, linkedin-api, react-share

By the way, I asked this question yesterday, but did not get the desired result.

I am trying to set sharing messaging via LinkedIn. I understand that to work your parameters have to be encoded. For example I made the link:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https%3A%2F%2Fathenatools.com%2Fafk&title=ATHENA%20Tools%20by%20Invitation%20Only&summary=Create%20Worlds%20in%20your%20dev%20tool%2010X%20faster%2C%2010X%20cheaper%20and%20in%20more%20detail!%20https%3A%2F%2Fathenatools.com%2Fafk%20BY%20INVITATION%20ONLY%20-%20you%20will%20need%20my%20referral%20code%20RFCODE2F%20to%20join.%20%23ATHENAtools&source=AthenaTools

Parameters in the API:
[image]

But it works and displays only one parameter correctly, the **link**:
[image]

So I did not give up and tried via the library [React-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-share), but it does not work either. For example I set parameters per the documentation:
[image]

But I get this:
[image]

**So, I need to add the title, description, and some code which will change every time when a user signs up and the desired image.**

Comment: try to use single quotes ' ' or double quotes instead of ` `

Comment: it didn't help, i m getting the same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is no longer possible.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin) To share rich media on linked in you have to become linked in business partner. After become linked in business partner then you'll have access to linkedIn API and you'll be able to share the desired content. Without becoming linkedIn business partner you can only share **URL** but not description, images or videos etc.
Have a look at this link. https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program